# My app updates not showing in the Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I have pushed a new version of my app.

On google developer console it is published and all old versions are unpublished but on Google Play Store it is still showing old version.

I already clear play store cached and data but still showing old app version don't know why.

I have checked, on all device showing old version.

Here is snapshot for google developer console

[image]

Comment: It takes 2-3 hours to appear..!! It is showing **Processing Update** at top right corner you can see that..!!

Comment: How much time I have to wait Uploaded on 09/06/2016 at 07:40 AM. It's too late. Normally take 2/3 hours to publish on play store but not it is more that 72 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App is live after 13 days, I have contact to google support center and also they have answer for this delay. But It is now clear that it may take any time to be live on play store. I was worried because this was happen first time during my 4 years career.

Comment: Waiting for 30h on my app to be available I found your post. In contrast to your screenshot there is nothing saying "processing update" in my dev console as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

You have just to wait a little bit. It may take some days until you see the newest version in google play store.

Comment: How much time I have to wait Uploaded on 09/06/2016 at 07:40 AM. It's too late. Normally take 2/3 hours to publish on play store

Answer (score 0):

Once you push it live from the publishing interface, it will take a max 2/3 hours to be live to consumers. Unlike iTunes, Google review does not involve any human testing so it is much quicker.

Comment: How much time I have to wait Uploaded on 09/06/2016 at 07:40 AM. It's too late. Normally take 2/3 hours to publish on play store

Comment: Completely false. Google play review almost always involve a human checking your app